# Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime): How to show a list of images in a FlipView?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, flipview

I'm doing this way:

```
    using Windows.Storage;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

    ...

    private async void LoadFiles()
    {
        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> list = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        var images = new List<BitmapImage>();
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (StorageFile file in list)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                images.Add(bitmapImage);

            }
        }
        flipView.ItemsSource = images;
    }
```

xaml

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView"
              SelectionChanged="flipView_SelectionChanged">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

I get this exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: The component cannot be found. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

at this line

```
 await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

Please, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program works but the problem was corrupted jpg files.
They had a 0 bytes size so the `stream` could not be created.
Check if this variable has been created or if it's full of data.